# VMWare Fusion: Failed to open kernel extension "com.vmware.kext.vmci": No such file or directory

Tags: vmware, vmware-fusion

We get this error occasionally when firing up the Virtual Machine in Macbook.

Have wasted an hour or two on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to VMWare being blocked by OSX.
Go to "System Preferences" => "Security & Privacy" => General

At the bottom of the Frame, you would see that the OS has blocked VM Ware. Allow the app to run and your problem is solved.

[image: Settings Pane]